# Third party cookies not set on Chrome (Django App)

Tags: django, google-chrome, cookies, session-cookies, samesite

I am having problems accessing some third-party cookies on Chrome.

Chrome version is `80.0.3987.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)` and I suppose this already have the new implementation of SameSite cookies set to Lax.

However, in the Django settings I have added the following:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
```

with no luck.

[image]

You can see there are no Cookies in the Request header above

[image]

I have tried the request I am having troubles executing from Chrome on Postman. I get exactly the same result until I pass `Cookie: sessionid: <some_id>`. It probably is worth mentioning that this whole things works with no problems on Firefox (where I can see the Cookie set properly in the request Headers).

If anyone has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK found the solution!

Based on the conversations on [this PR](https://github.com/django/django/pull/11894) I decided to go for the following workaround:

1. Create the [following middleware](https://gist.github.com/acu192/315d27f8fe9ff58638c3571c91c4d1ca)
2. Add the middleware before `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware`
3. Still keep those settings.

=>

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
```

The PR above is already merged into master and it will be released sometime in August 2020. Until then, this is the best workaround.

Comment: This is the correct solution as of August 11 on Django 2.2.

Comment: For Django 3.1, there should be quotes according to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#session-cookie-samesite):
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'